# Batch File - Read txt file and reformat the text

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a pretty horrible looking txt file, and am looking for a way to reformat the content of the file. An example of the file is shown below

```
{'4': 20947, 's': 3263, '6': 20837, 'A': 3490, 'U': 3467, 'g': 3277, 'd': 3245, 'H': 3534, 'Y': 3534, 'm': 3297, 'r': 3400, 'u': 3157, 'X': 3501, 'i': 3354, '2': 21012, 'V': 3398, '3': 20864, 'G': 3528, 'M': 3540, '\n': 30212, 'n': 3296, 'T': 3620, 'R': 3500, 'j': 3205, 'W': 3512, 'N': 3483, 'v': 3260, 'I': 3488, 'e': 3179, 'w': 3290, 'P': 3575, '0': 9455, 'L': 3473, 'q': 3284, '1': 21093, 'b': 3216, '9': 18626, 'F': 3494, '8': 20916, '7': 20746, 'x': 3231, 'o': 3162, 'y': 3295, '5': 21467, 'p': 3245, 'E': 3535, 'Q': 3345, 'K': 3619, 'h': 3320, 'f': 3295, 'l': 3284, 'D': 3590, 'c': 3258, 'C': 3473, 'k': 3213, 'a': 3023, 'J': 3504, 't': 3246, 'O': 3463, 'S': 3522, 'B': 3514}
```

I want to be able to read the character in quotes '' and then print the value that follows after the colon, in alphanumerical order. For example:

```
a: 1233
A: 2345
b: 1023
B: 1542
c: 2415
# And so on....
```

For ease, I thought doing this via a batch file would be ideal, however do not know how to go about doing this - any help would be great!

Comment: is there any relationship between the numbers in the source file and those in the destination?

Comment: Yeah, just the same numbers in source file as in the destination. Apologies, my example didn't accurately show this. The source file contains the count of each individual character occurrence from another text file, and I just want to be able to format it better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove all charcters that you don't need, then parse with a plain `for`. Sort the output, done.

```
@echo off
<input.txt set /p line=
set line=%line:{=%
set line=%line:}=%
set line=%line:'=%
set line=%line: =%
((for %%i in (%line%) do @echo %%i)|sort)>output.txt
```

Comment: Nice one, this is exactly what I was after, thanks for help!

So this prints the desired format to the console - how would I then print this to file? Forgive me, somewhat of a cmd noob!

Comment: just redirect to a file. You want the output of the complete `for` loop, so enclose that with parantheses, so you can redirect the whole thing in one go. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you need for the space to appear after the colon, then you might try:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

<crackline.txt set /p line=

set line=%line:{=%
set line=%line:}=%
set line=%line:'=%
set line=%line: =%

for %%i in (%line%) do (
    set L=%%i
    @echo !L::=: !
)
```